# Inserting equivalent number of white spaces as each integer in an ArrayList in a 2-d matrix (Adjacency Matrix)

Tags: java, swing

I have a problem while solving the white spaces issue in an adjacency matrix. Assuming the matrix looks like this

```
             America India Australia Canada Russia
   America      01100
   India        00100
   Australia    00000
   Canada       01010
   Russia       10101
```

I need to insert spaces between the 0's and 1's such that they are systematically arranged right below the column(horizontal labels) names like this.

```
             America India Australia Canada Russia
   America      0      1       1        0     0
   India        0      0       1        0     0
   Australia    0      0       0        0     0
   Canada       0      1       0        1     0
   Russia       1      0       1        0     1
```

Code:

```
    private void display(List<String> a){ //this list is the name of countries

    List<Integer> wordDistances = new ArrayList<>();

    int p = 0;
    while (p < vertexCount){
        if(p == vertexCount-1){
            break;
        }
        int x = ((a.get(p).length())/2)+((a.get(p+1).length())/2)+2;
        System.out.println(x); //to check what numbers are we getting
        wordDistances.add(x);           
        p++;            
    }
    wordDistances.add(0); //added zero so that this list has the same number of elements as the list of name of countries
    System.out.println(wordDistances); //again to check

    System.out.print("\t");
    for(int i = 0;i < vertexCount; i++){
        System.out.print(" "+ a.get(i)); //prints column
    }
    System.out.println();
    for(int i = 0; i < vertexCount; i++){
        System.out.print(a.get(i) + "\t  "); //prints row
        for(int j = 0;j < vertexCount; j++){
            System.out.print(adjMatrix[i][j]);              
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

the List "wordDistances" adds the length of whitespaces needed. How should I proceed now ?

P.S. The label names, that is the row and column names are not constant. It can change and the matrix size can be anywhere between 1x1 to nxn size.

Answer (score 0):

So after few trial and error method, I compromised with the length of labels by making another class that would take the list of Country names and trim it down to exactly 5 characters/alphabets in each word.

Code:

```
    private void replaceListWords(List<String> ListVerticeWords){
    List<String> properListVertices = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < ListVerticeWords.size(); i++){
        String temp = "";
        if(ListVerticeWords.get(i).length() > 5){//if length is more then cut it and store
            temp = ListVerticeWords.get(i).substring(0, 4) + ".";
        }else if(ListVerticeWords.get(i).length() < 5){//if length is less then add spaces
            int tempLength = 5 - ListVerticeWords.get(i).length();
            temp = ListVerticeWords.get(i);
            for(int j = 0; j < tempLength; j++){
                temp = temp + " ";
            }
        }else{//else store as it is
            temp = ListVerticeWords.get(i);
        }           
        properListVertices.add(temp);           
    }       
    //System.out.println(properListVertices);//delete
    System.out.println("\nThe Adjacency Matrix is drawn below: ");
    display(properListVertices);//displays the matrix
}
```

After this I made few changes to the display class.

Code:

```
    private void display(List<String> listVertice){     
    List<Integer> wordDistances = new ArrayList<>();

    int p = 0;
    while (p < vertexCount){
        if(p == vertexCount-1){
            break;
        }           
        int left = (listVertice.get(p).length())/2;
        int right = (listVertice.get(p+1).length())/2;          
        //System.out.print(left+" ");//delete
        //System.out.print(right+"    ");//delete           
        int x = left + right + 1;           
        //System.out.println(x); // delete  
        wordDistances.add(x);           
        p++;            
    }
    wordDistances.add(1); //added 1 instead of 0 because the calculation down would show error
    //System.out.println("");//delete
    //System.out.println(wordDistances); // delete

    System.out.print("\n\t");
    for(int i = 0;i < vertexCount; i++){
        System.out.print(listVertice.get(i) + " "); //prints column
    }
    System.out.println();
    for(int i = 0; i < vertexCount; i++){
        System.out.print(listVertice.get(i) + "\t  "); //prints row
        for(int j = 0;j < vertexCount; j++){
            System.out.print(adjMatrix[i][j]);
             int count = wordDistances.get(j);
             String spaces = String.format("%"+count+"s", "");
             System.out.print(spaces);              
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Display/Output:

```
 There are 5 number of Nodes and those are [America, India, Australia, Canada, Russia]

 The Adjacency Matrix is drawn below:

         Amer. India Aust. Cana. Russ.
  Amer.    0     1     1     0     0
  India    0     0     1     0     0
  Aust.    0     0     0     0     0
  Cana.    0     1     0     1     0
  Russ.    1     0     1     0     1
```